# HTML Code Coverage Report with Visual C++ and Catch

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, code-coverage

I have a C++ project which uses cmake to build for Unix with gcc and Windows with Visual Studio. The project uses the Catch unit testing framework (https://github.com/philsquared/Catch)

Now for Unix I can create a HTML code coverage report with gcov/lcov.

Does anyone know a similar tool like gcov and lcov that can be used to create HTML code coverage reports under Windows with the Microsoft compiler? It must work with the MSBuild system on the console and should not rely on an installed Visual Studio, so it can be used on a build server.

I am aware of the possibility to use things like Cygwin, MinGW or MSYS2 but I was hoping there is something that can be used with the MS C++ compiler and the MSBuild system.